# How to iterate specific table column in django form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a select menu which shows a list of foreign languages in English.  I would like to show the list in Spanish or Japanese depending on which language the site is currently being viewed in.

The form on my template page renders en (English) by default. This is what it looks like in my template page:

```
{{ form.native }}
```

My form knows the current language the site is being viewed in from the "this_language" parameter. My form looks like this:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        if 'this_language' in kwargs:
            this_language = kwargs.pop('this_language')
            super(RegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['native'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Language.objects.all().order_by(this_language), empty_label=_('Please select'))
```

The model looks like this:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    en = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    es = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    ja = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.en
```

I noticed I can change "return self.en" in the model to either es or js and i get the desired result.

But is it possible to do this dynamically in the template page or in the forms.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a chance to try it, but if you want to show a different display for `ModelChoiceField` other than using `__unicode__`, you can define your own form field. It inherits from `ModelChoiceField`, but override `label_from_instance` method:

```
class LanguageChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.language = kwargs.pop('language', None)
        super(LanguageChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
         # return the field you want to display
         if self.language:
             return getattr(obj, self.language)
         return obj.en

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # your code
    self.fields['native'] = LanguageChoiceField(language=this_language, queryset=...)
```